# Expand CSS outer wrapper to fit all monitors

Tags: html, css, wrapper

All the content of my site is centred in the main wrapper of my page. What I am trying to do is if the resolution of the screen gets bigger have a second wrapper expand and fill the space with a second background.

If you look at this site you will understand what I mean. http://www.cclonline.com/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The site you linked doesn't appear to have anything expanding, it's hard coded like that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. How would I get my page to do this?

Comment: By saying, "have a second wrapper expand and fill the space with a second background" if you mean to have it white, I'd recommend putting another div with z-index lesser than wrapper and footer, then set its width relative to screen size (in percentage).